# (In Jenkins) How to build job which is inside folder using REST API?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have installed Folder plugin and created folder.  This folder has 3 jobs.

- Child 1
- Child 2
- BuildThemAll (buildall)

Out of 3 job, one job is multi phase job which will build other two jobs. Using REST API, I want to build "BuildThemAll" job.

When i tried to do it, Jenkins returned with 404 error.

(Following is API URL, I tried with get and post)
192.168.0.15:8080/job/buildall/build?token=8aba9207684c229561ae9d3f1c7e8a8c

Same result observed with "Child 1" and "Child 2" .. However, I have standard maven based job outside this folder and it works fine with this API.

I also tried placing foldername/jobname/build... but no luck here as well.

Will appreciate help.

Answer (score 0):

I moved job "BuildThemAll" to root of Jenkins.  This way, I could trigger using API.  Now in configuration of this job, I kept child job name as "modules/child1", "module/child2" (module is folder name.)